# xslant mathematically

Tags: tikz-pgf

How is the `xslant` coordinate transformation operation of `tikz` defined mathematically?

For example, let `A = (x_0, y_0)` and `xslant = k`. What is the mathematical expression for the transformed coordinate `B = (x_1, y_1)`?

I want to understand how the pgf manual example works:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[help lines] (0,0) grid (3,2);
\draw                (0,0) -- (1,1) -- (1,0);
\draw[xslant=2,blue] (0,0) -- (1,1) -- (1,0);
\draw[xslant=-1,red] (0,0) -- (1,1) -- (1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: For me, that looks like a shear at first glance.

Comment: In my opinion, it is `x_1=x_0+k`, `y_1=y_0`

Comment: @karlkoeller: it is not. That would be `xshift`.

Comment: `x_1=x_0+k*y_0` and `y_1=y_0`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As Mark Wibrow says in his comment `xslant=k` replace `x` by `x+k*y`.
So it is a shortcut to `cm={1,0,k,1,(0,0)}`.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[myxslant/.style={cm={1,0,#1,1,(0,0)}}]
    \draw[help lines] (0,0) grid (3,2);
    \draw                (0,0) -- (1,1) -- (1,0);
    \draw[myxslant=2,blue] (0,0) -- (1,1) -- (1,0);
    \draw[myxslant=-1,red] (0,0) -- (1,1) -- (1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

**NOTE :** There is a [bug in the documentation](http://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/bugs/339/) of `cm` (PGF 2.0, 2.1 and 3.0): the matrix is the transpose of what it claims.

Comment: I think that bug is there since v2.00 (which is I guess more than 5 years ago)

Comment: @percusse It was not reported as bug before, I think. May be in 3.1 it will be no more ;)

Comment: I think there were two If I remember correctly ;)

Comment: @percusse wow ! I was not able to find this reports when I did this one. May be the third will be the decisive one ;)